# Is it OK to do additive smoothing before applying Pearson's chi-square test for independence?

Tags: bayesian, chi-squared-test, smoothing, frequentist

I'm concerned about treating my data as gold, especially in areas of low data support, so I would like to apply [additive smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing).  I'm then doing several things with this data, and one of them is [Pearson's chi-square test for independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test#Test_of_independence).  Is it still acceptable to first do the smoothing and then do the chi-square test?  The former is very Bayesian and the latter is very frequentist, so at this at least feels somewhat strange.

However, it seems like smoothing should curtail the need to worry much about the data support or the need for something like Fisher's exact test.

My reasoning for wanting to use these competing philosophies is because the audience really wants to see p-values, but the Bayesian inside of me is fighting to be let loose. As such I came up with this compromise.

EDIT: To clarify how I envision the smoothing taking place, consider the following contingency table:

```
    X=0  X=1
   +-------+
Y=0|  2|  2|
   +---+---+
Y=1|  3|  3|
   +---+---+
```

So without smoothing we have:

$P(X=0)=\frac{5}{10}$, $P(X=1)=\frac{5}{10}$, $P(Y=0)=\frac{4}{10}$, $P(Y=1)=\frac{6}{10}$

With additive smoothing and say $\alpha=1$ we get:

$P(X=0)=\frac{6}{12}$, $P(X=1)=\frac{6}{12}$, $P(Y=0)=\frac{5}{12}$, $P(Y=1)=\frac{7}{12}$

I haven't yet decided how to handle the contingency table.  One way would be to smooth each cell:

```
    X=0  X=1
   +-------+
Y=0|  3|  3|
   +---+---+
Y=1|  4|  4|
   +---+---+
```

Comment: How does one even apply the $\chi^2$ test to smoothed data?  Regardless, the smoothing is going to change the sampling distribution and introduce *dependencies,* thereby ruining the $\chi^2$ test.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I still don't follow, because according to the edit you appear to be smoothing both the estimators of the marginal distributions *and* you seem to be changing the data!  The former is ok, subject to some conditions (although it does nothing to change the "data support"), but--again--if you smooth the data, it's hard even to know what is being tested here.

Comment: This seems vaguely like a test of independence for BB($\alpha,\alpha,N_i$)-distributed variables, but I wouldn't stake much on it. You'd probably be better off using Fisher's exact test - I'm not sure what your worry is with support.

Comment: @sesqu I don't think Fisher's exact test scales up, so I would have to use one technique for "small" datasets and another for "large" datasets, which has a number of drawbacks for my purposes.  As for data support, I'm concerned because there is a big difference between 25% and 0%, but not so much between 1 out of 4 and 0 out of 4.  I'm not sure that smoothing will solve this issue, but I thought it was worth a try.

Comment: This smoothing scheme really only does much when some counts are very low, in which case Fisher's test is fast. If you do have datasets with large and small counts, Yates's continuity corrected chi-square might be sufficient.

Comment: I thought Yates' continuity correction didn't work for general `n x m` contingency tables.  In case my post wasn't clear, I'm not guaranteed to always have `2x2`, even though the example was.

Comment: If you want to "smooth" (use a prior) then why not take it all the way home and do a formal Bayesian hypothesis test for independence? If you're dealing with straight contingency tables (no correlated observations or other complications) then I think you ought to be able to compute marginal likelihoods and Bayes factors analytically using Dirichlet (or just uniform) priors.

Comment: @JMS Basically my audience wants to see p-values, and the Bayesian inside of me is doing what it can while still giving the audience what they want to see.  So this post was my compromise between somewhat conflicting philosophies.

Comment: @Michael McGowan If they want p-values so badly then it's hard to justify any kind of smoothing IMO. @whuber's comments are on the money; you've induced dependency *and* muddied up the sampling distribution.